# I need to Hide <tr> in a table when i click Addnew button(WORDPRESS,PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

```
   Add new button
```

---

```
<div class="icon32 icon32-posts-post" id="icon-edit"><br></div>
    <h2><?php _e('Collaboration', 'custom_table_example')?> <a  class="add-new-h2" id=" add_new"
    href="<?php echo get_admin_url(get_current_blog_id(),   'admin.php?page=persons_form');?>"><?php _e('Add   new','custom_table_example')?> </a>
 </h2>
```

```
    (Need to hide) 
-----------------------------------------
 <tr class="form-field" id="appid">
    <th valign="top" scope="row">
        <label for="Application_ID"><?php _e('Application ID',  'custom_table_example')?></label>
    </th>
    <td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

How to hide when AddNew  Button is clicked??
    I cannot directly give hide or display:none because "Edit and Add new"     uses the same form.so on-click of Add new i need to hide tablerow
    Also i had tried giving on-click function(Javascript)      "document.getElementById("appid").style.display = 'none';"
    still i didn't get any response.
    Can any one of you help me please!!! Thanks in advance
   Refer to this link [wordpress-custom-database-table-example-full](http://mac-blog.org.ua/wordpress-custom-database-table-example-full/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("add_new").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    document.getElementById("appid").style.display = 'none';
    event.preventDefault()
});
</script>
```

Comment: <?php 
echo'
<script>
function myfunction()
{ Your code}
</script>';
?>
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="icon32 icon32-posts-post" id="icon-edit"><br></div>
    <h2><?php _e('Collaboration', 'custom_table_example')?> <a class="add-new-h2" id=" add_new" onclick="myfunction();"
                                 href="<?php echo get_admin_url(get_current_blog_id(), 'admin.php?page=persons_form');?>"><?php _e('Add new','custom_table_example')?> </a>

    </h2>
     Brother i tried in this way page its not reloading....!!!!!

Comment: its not working fine with the above code @Ravindra Reddy